# Rails carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, carrierwave

I have created some dynamic attributes for model and add some code(setter/getter) in model to define these attributes as a instance variables for this model. and all this working fine.

I am Using key/value pair to stored the value of these dynamic attributes.

I want to use these attributes with carrierwave to upload image. Once image is uploaded then I'll stored this image on aws s3 and key/value pair only hold the name of the upload, just like carrierwave is doing.

Do we have any better option/suggestion.

We can go other than of carrierwave......Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth using paperclip with AWS-SDK

Gemfile:-

```
gem "paperclip" 
gem 'aws-sdk',   :require => "aws-sdk"
```

Model Code:-

```
    has_attached_file :image,
                  :styles => {
                  :tiny => "35x35",
                  :thumb => "250x250",
                  :large => "600x600"
                              }, 
:storage => :s3,
:bucket => 'BUCKET NAME',
:s3_credentials => {
  :access_key_id => 'xxxxxxxxxxYOUr ACCESS KEY IDxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  :secret_access_key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxYOUR SECRET ACCESS KEYxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
```

Hope This helps